# Eclipse: Launch plug-in from web page

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to launch the Eclipse plug-in from a web page?

I'm working on a project where, ideally, I'd like to launch an Eclipse plug-in from a web application. The web application contains information related to the code then, when the user gets to a certain point, I'd like the user to be able to click an "Edit Code" button. At that point, I'd like Eclipse to launch for the selected code, meaning the context is passed over the Eclipse.

Comment: No.   There is not.

Comment: It doesn't work in the same way but you might want to look at [Eclipse RAP](https://eclipse.org/rap/)

Comment: Thank you, @OldProgrammer .

Comment: @greg-449 - Thank you for the suggestion! I'm reading through the the RAP site. So, it's a web-based IDE version of Eclipse, in a sense? Do you know if you can create plug-ins for it as you would for Eclipse?

Comment: I don't use RAP but my understanding is you write plugins the same way as a traditional Eclipse RCP.

Comment: @greg-449 - Thanks so much! I'm going to look into it. I appreciate! Wish I could give you some reputation points or the answer for this question.